# issue with mysql STR_TO_DATE() function ending characters

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I am trying to use the str_to_Date function to convert a string like

```
'30/09/2010 3:33:51 p.m.' and '30/09/2010 12:00:00 a.m.'(excluding quotations)
```

to convert into a date time.

However, I am having trouble adding the last characters being 'p.m.' or 'a.m.' to function

What I have tried is

```
SET datecolumn = STR_TO_DATE(left(datecolumn(23), '%d/%m%Y %h:%i:%s %_.m.')
```

<---- returns error code
and

```
SET datecolumn = STR_TO_DATE(left(datecolumn(18), '%d/%m%Y %h:%i:%s')
```

<-- But this one excludes the
'a.m.' or 'p.m.'

TIA

Comment: The format character %p handles AM and PM. But I don't know if it handles a.m. and p.m. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

For manageAM/PM Use `p%`

```
SET datecolumn = STR_TO_DATE(left(datecolumn(23), '%d/%m%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE()` to remove the dots from am/pm and apply the correct format:

```
set datecolumn = str_to_date(
    replace(left(datecolumn, 24), '.', ''),
    '%d/%m/%Y %r'
)
```

I use the function `LEFT()` because it exists in your code, although I don't know if it is really needed.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6FzGzqKWLdAF9xjTnHZA1r/1).
Results:

```
| date                |
| ------------------- |
| 2010-09-30 15:33:51 |
| 2010-09-30 00:00:00 |
```